# A standalone Rasp pi running a web server. Possible?

Tags: server, raspberry-pi

I have a rasp pi 3 which controls an irrigation system. The pi is headless, and is controlled via the home network by running a Tomcat server, which creates a UI. Mostly, the irrigation system is automatic, but I can log in to the Tomcat server to see the log of its activities, or change settings, or update the planting plan or manually control the sprinklers.

Now I'd like something similar, but in a place where there is no internet available. That is, I'd like to use the pi as a standalone web server, so that I can access the UI using a browser on my phone. I've looked through the rasp pi documentation, but it describes setting up access points, which seem to depend on a wired connection between the pi and the router. I've read about connecting via SSH to a standalone setup, but that article said that support for a standalone server isn't available.

Is what I'm looking for possible?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Of course it is. `I've looked through the rasp pi documentation, but it describes setting up access points, which seem to depend on a wired connection between the pi and the router.` The connection to the router is only required if your RPI is supposed to be a Wifi access point to the internet. Connecting locally to the RPI (and all other devices connected to this Wifi Network) is always possible.

Comment: You will either need to connect the Raspberry Pi to a mobile data network, a local WiFi network, or a local ethernet.  Or you can have the Raspberry Pi create its own WiFi network.  I don't think you've given enough details for us to select one of those solutions for you and this isn't really about software development.

Comment: I followed the instructions once more for setting up the local network, and this time it's worked. I don't know why it worked this time when previously it didn't, repeatedly. Oh well. Thanks.